# How to fix QObject::connect: No such slot.. when connecting a sender to a slot both in the same class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am writing a programm, that creates a QLineEdit that only accepts digits and should, when it rejects an input that is not a digit, turn the background to some abitrary color. If the input is accpeted it will turn the background white again. Now I need to connect the inputRejected and textEdited events of the QLineEdit to randomcolor() and white() respectively, but the connect is making me trouble and i do not know how to fix it.

This is the first time I'm working with the connect and i slugged through many forums alreay trying out the different Syntax i found there.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class OnlyNumbers : QLineEdit {
   public:
        static int spawn(int argc, char *argv[]){
            QApplication app(argc, argv);
            OnlyNumbers P;
            return app.exec();
        }
        OnlyNumbers() : QLineEdit() {
            this->setValidator(new QIntValidator());
            QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(inputRejected()), this, SLOT(randomcolor()));
            QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(&QLineEdit::textEdited(const QString)), this, SLOT(&OnlyNumbers::white()));
            QRegExp rx("[0-9]*");            QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);
            this->setValidator(validator);
            this->show();

        }
    public slots:
        void randomcolor(){
            this->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(std::rand()%256, rand()%256, rand()%256); selection-background-color: rgb(rand()%256, rand()%256, rand()%256); }");
        }
        void white(){
            this->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(255, 255, 255); selection-background-color: rgb(233, 99, 0); }");
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return OnlyNumbers::spawn(argc, argv);
}
```

> QObject::connect: No such slot QLineEdit::randomcolor()
>
> QObject::connect: No such signal QLineEdit::&QLineEdit::textEdited(const QString)

These are the errors i get, and i don't know what to do with them, because for em the two are existant. Sadly I cannot describe my problem better, because i don't know more.

SOLVED: The Problem was, that i didn't seperate calls definition and declaration in onlynumbers.h and onlynumbers.cpp. Also i cannot put std::rand()%256 in the string i need to split the string and concatonate it with all the numbers converted to a qstring. :D Thanks for the help. You gave me the motivation to keep googeling.

Comment: Replace `QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(&QLineEdit::textEdited(const QString)), this, SLOT(&OnlyNumbers::white()));` with `QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString)), this, SLOT(white()));` you seem to be mixing the Qt4 annd Qt5 connect methods.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the old string based signal/slot connection syntax with the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros any more. Better to use the new - [compile time checked,  pointer to member function based syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#). It's both safer and faster.

Comment: You could also use the Qt5 syntax `QObject::connect(this, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this,&OnlyNumbers::white);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `Q_OBJECT` for your class. For example:

```
class OnlyNumbers : QLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT    
    ...
```

See the documentation on [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html):

> Notice that the Q_OBJECT macro is mandatory for any object that implements signals, slots or properties.

Without the macro the meta compiler simply will not generate the information needed for the slots/signals declared in your class.

Also, after `Q_OBJECT` has been added you should rerun `qmake` on your project since `qmake` actually generates the calls to `moc` in the makefile. This is explained by the documentation of the [Meta-Object Compiler (moc)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html):

> Whenever qmake is run, it parses the project's header files and generates make rules to invoke moc for those files that contain a Q_OBJECT macro.

Also as mentioned in the comments - the `SIGNAL/SLOT` macros are the old string based implementation, and there are many benefits to switch to the new compile time checked connect - see [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and [Differences between String-Based and Functor-Based Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#).

Comment: With the new compile time checked syntax, `Q_OBJECT` is no longer needed for slots. Only for signals.

Comment: After adding     Q_OBJECT i am getting     undefined reference to `vtable for OnlyNumbers' and     collect2.exe:-1: Fehler: error: ld returned 1 exit status. It read this error comes from my compiler, so im giving the code to one of my friends to test, because i don't get what i should do with this error

Comment: That means `moc` was not run after the change. You may have to run `QMake` or regenerate your project depending on how you are building.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that is a very good point, I'll fix the answer:) But the guy is still using `SIGNAL/SLOT` macros, so it is relevant for him.

Comment: Yes please add the fix for the signal / slot problem. This answer does not address the main issue with the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I updated the answer but looking at QT docs I could not find a reference to the statement that `Q_OBJECT` is no longer needed for slots. Can you maybe share a link for that? Since I was not aware of that, but I'd actually like to read and understand why/how the new functor based syntax lifts the meta info only from slots. Thanks:)

Comment: @drescherjm well, op's main problem was missing `Q_OBJECT`. I expanded the answer that he needs to rerun qmake, but what did you mean with "answer does not address the main issue" ?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis It falls out, quite naturally, of the fact that you are now connecting to regular member functions, functors, lambdas. Of course there is no need for the `Q_OBJECT` macro to do that. It's just plain C++. This may be helpful:  https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @JesperJuhl @drescherjm @RudolfsBundulis Q_OBJECT was definitely missing, when using ```QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(inputRejected()), this, SLOT(randomcolor()));
        QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString)), this, SLOT(white()));```. The main thing though after that was to seperate the class into its header and definiton. Thanks a lot for your help!